# iTextSharp HTML to PDF with ParseXHtml unicode characters are not parsed

Tags: html, asp.net, pdf, unicode, itext

first of all I've been dealing with this problem for the past 2 days and I thought I may finally ask it since I've not found any working solution. First let me introduce the problem then I'll explain what I've tried.

As the title introduces, I'm trying to convert HTML to PDF using iTextSharp, the HTML includes gridview as well.

```
 using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {


                System.Text.Encoding Enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont STF_Helvetica_Turkish = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont("Helvetica", "CP1254", iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

                iTextSharp.text.Font fontNormal = new iTextSharp.text.Font(STF_Helvetica_Turkish, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);

                StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
                string contentHtml = PrintElem();
                contentHtml = contentHtml.Replace("Ş", "S");
                contentHtml = contentHtml.Replace("İ", "I");
                contentHtml = contentHtml.Replace("ı", "i");
                contentHtml = contentHtml.Replace("Ğ", "G");
                contentHtml = contentHtml.Replace("Ü", "U");
                contentHtml = contentHtml.Replace("ğ", "g");
                contentHtml = contentHtml.Replace("ş", "s");
                StringReader srHtml = new StringReader(contentHtml);
                Stream denemeStream = GenerateStreamFromString(srHtml.ToString());



                iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, ms);

                pdfDoc.Open();

                using (var msCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PrintElem().ToString())))
                {
                    using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PrintElem().ToString())))
                    {
                        //iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerFontProvider();

                        //Parse the HTML
                        iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, msHtml, (Stream)null);
                    }
                }

                //iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, denemeStream,null,Encoding.UTF8);
                pdfDoc.Close();

                MemoryStream ret = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
                return ret;



            }
        }
```

As you can see last solution I tried was to change all turkish characters to english ones yet the pdf output still did not display them.
So far I've tried changing encoding to everything offered on the internet. I tried to add the font yet I've failed to do it as you can see I'm not using that overloaded function of ParseXHtml (if you know how to add this fontNormal to the parsing I'll gladly try that out as well).

the PrintElem function returns the following HTML content (or similar ones that contain turkish characters inside)

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <h3 align='center'>ABG SİGORTA ALACAK/VERECEK MUTABAKAT EKSTRESİ</h3>
      <style>#ContentPlaceHolder1_vaultsListGridview{width: 100%;} td:nth-child(3) {text-align: right;}td:nth-child(4) {text-align: right;}.netWorthClass{text-align: right;}</style>
   </head>
   <body >
      <br/>
      <div>Kasa Adı = 1</div>
      <div>Devir = 56 TL</div>
      <br/>
      <div>
         \r\n\t
         <table class=\"table table-hover table-striped\" cellspacing=\"0\" rules=\"all\" border=\"1\" id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_vaultsListGridview\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse;\">
            \r\n\t\t
            <thead>
               \r\n\t\t\t
               <tr>
                  \r\n\t\t\t\t
                  <th scope=\"col\">Tarih</th>
                  <th scope=\"col\">Açıklama</th>
                  <th scope=\"col\">Giren</th>
                  <th scope=\"col\">Çıkan</th>
                  \r\n\t\t\t
               </tr>
               \r\n\t\t
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               \r\n\t\t\t
               <tr>
                  \r\n\t\t\t\t
                  <td>\r\n                                                    <span id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_vaultsListGridview_fullDateLabel_0\">26/05/2017</span>\r\n                                                </td>
                  <td>\r\n                                                    <span id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_vaultsListGridview_detailLabel_0\">MART AYI KALAN VE NİSAYIN AYI SSK ÖDEMESİ</span>\r\n                                                </td>
                  <td>\r\n                                                    0\r\n                                                </td>
                  <td>\r\n                                                    1,295.00\r\n                                                </td>
                  \r\n\t\t\t
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  \r\n\t\t\t\t
                  <td>\r\n                                                    <span id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_vaultsListGridview_fullDateLabel_1\">31/05/2017</span>\r\n                                                </td>
                  <td>\r\n                                                    <span id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_vaultsListGridview_detailLabel_1\">NİSAN AYI KOMİSYON</span>\r\n                                                </td>
                  <td>\r\n                                                    1,351.00\r\n                                                </td>
                  <td>\r\n                                                    0\r\n                                                </td>
                  \r\n\t\t\t
               </tr>
               \r\n\t\t
            </tbody>
            \r\n\t
         </table>
         \r\n
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class='netWorthClass'>Giren Miktar = 1351 TL</div>
      <div class='netWorthClass'>Çıkan Miktar = 1295 TL</div>
      <br/>
   </body>
</html>
```

I've taken the above html part from debugger sorry for the mess, but you see the problematic characters above.

I'll gladly try out everything you may offer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is wrong: the characters are parsed but not rendered. They aren't rendered because you don't provide the correct `FontProvider`. Please read the documentation: [How to make Cyrillic characters display properly when converting HTML to PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-make-cyrillic-characters-display-properly-when-converting-html-pdf) [How to convert Arabic HTML to PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-convert-arabic-html-pdf) [How to export Vietnamese text to PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-export-vietnamese-text-pdf-using-itext)

Comment: The examples show how to display Cyrillic, Arabic, and Asian characters, but the principle is the same for Turkish characters. Provide the right font, use the right encoding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the issue is that I do not want to provide a directory for a font. How can I use the Font class for this purpose, I've mentioned that above too.

Comment: You *need* a font program. You can provide the *path* to that font program, or you can provide that font as a `byte` array, but if you do not provide a font program, your question can't be answered. You claim "I've mentioned that above too", but it's not clear what you mean by that.

Comment: I've tried adding the following css
style='font - family: Arial Unicode MS, FreeSans; font - size:16px; font - weight: normal; '
and registered the font like
fontImp.Register(Server.MapPath("~/fonts/FreeSans.ttf"));

No luck though, VS2017's html visualizer displays everything correctly yet the pdf output is messed up